# Is it possible to specify limit via where clause in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible? I mean

```
Select * from tbl limit 100;
```

I want to replace with a query like

```
Select * from tbl WHERE ...some_condition...
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to print first 100 rows without using limit but with wherec lause

Comment: Technically you could use ROW_NUMBER() and subselect and all that, but not sure if it's smart.

Comment: So what's wrong using `limit`?

Comment: You want `LIMIT` but without using `LIMIT`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `row_number()` for that:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over () as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn <= 100
```

If you have a specific ordering in mind, you can add an `order by` clause:

```
select  row_number() over (order by date_column) as rn
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the `where` clause only applied to the first hundred rows?  If so, use a subquery:

```
select . . .
from (select t.*
      from table t
      limit 100) t
where . . .
```

This will return less than 100 rows (presumably not all rows match the condition).  Also, when using `limit`, you should have an `order by` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a `limit` clause inside a `where` clause. But you can of course *append* a `limit` clause after the `where` clause.